# Check that a pandas dataframe has data older than date.

Tags: python, pandas, timestamp

I currently have a `DataFrame` which has data indexed by a date. This data is in order. I want to be sure that the `DataFrame` has data from at least `2015-01-01`.

Since the data is in ascending order, it occurred to me to check the date of the first row, if that row is before `2015-01-01` this means the data is ok.

```
def date_from_filter(date_from, df):
    date = datetime.datetime.strptime(date_from, '%Y-%m-%d').date()
    return df.iloc[0].name <= date
```

`datefrom` is a String.

I'm getting a type error: `TypeError: Cannot compare type 'Timestamp' with type 'date'`.

What's the proper way to compare a date (or a string) to a pandas Timestamp?

Or, even better, what would be the proper way to check that the DataFrame contains data older than a certain date?

Comment: you should be able to just do `df.loc[df.index <= '2015-01-01']` and then just check the `len` of the returned df

Comment: Change that last line to - `df.iloc[0].name.date() <= date`. That should give you a boolean series through which you can use an `if/else` block to process further information. Or, you can try the more cleaner approach as EdChum mentioned.

Comment: Both things work!